# log4net stop working logging the first user after new release

Tags: log4net

My problem is that in development and test environment the code works fine, but when released to production it doesn't work as well.
After the release it will log the first users request which is about 9 different log entries when in INFO level. After the initial 9 nothing more gets logged until the server is restarted. I have now just this bare code in production and it still shows the same behavior.
Any suggestions of what could be causing this?

Configuration:

```xml
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <reconnectonerror value="true" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="Data Source=SQLHOTELL-FT,10433;Initial Catalog=BEKS;Integrated Security=True" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception],[UserId]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception, @userid)" />
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date"/> <dbType value="DateTime"/> <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
  </parameter>     
  <parameter>      
    <parameterName value="@thread"/> <dbType value="String"/> <size value="255"/> <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>     
  <parameter>       
    <parameterName value="@log_level"/> <dbType value="String"/> <size value="50"/> <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>     
  <parameter>        
    <parameterName value="@logger"/> <dbType value="String"/> <size value="255"/> <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
    </layout>
 </parameter>      
 <parameter>      
    <parameterName value="@message"/> <dbType value="String"/> <size value="4000"/> <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>      
  <parameter>        
    <parameterName value="@exception"/> <dbType value="String"/> <size value="2000"/> <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
</appender>
<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
  <applicationName value="BeksWebInterface" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="FATAL" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>
</appender>    
</log4net>
```

Code:

```cs
public static class Log
{
    private static ILog log;

    public static void CreateLogEntry(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Log));

            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

            log.Info(message);

        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you first get the logger and then configure the log4net? Usually it is the other way around. E.g.

```
// Configure log4net
var info = new FileInfo("myapp.log4net");
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(info);

// get the logger
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
```

Comment: Most likely because the example I looked at did it that way. Since it worked just fine in development and test I haven´t any particular reason to change them.